# Animated TV show about King Arthur and the Knights of the Round Table

Tags: story-identification, tv, arthurian, animated-series

I'm looking for an animated TV show based on King Arthur and the Knights of the Round Table. It came out some time in the 80s or early 90s. It centres around the Table and the Knights. All the Knights would place their swords on the Round Table. The Knights of the round table all had the same swords that were different from the other Knights. I think it was just a special black cross piece on the hilt.

In the intro they showed the building or rebuilding of castle Camelot. They lifted the Round Table into place with rope. It had magic and monsters like much of the fiction about King Arthur. All the Knights wore the same clothes and armor.

It is not *King Arthur and the Knights of Justice* or *The Legend of Prince Valiant* or *King Arthur & the Knights of the Round Table" ("Entaku no Kishi Monogatari Moero Āsā")* or *Arthur! and the Square Knights of the Round Table* or *Camelot Enchanted Tales* or *Arthur! and the Square Knights of the Round Table*

Out of all of these, it is most like 'Camelot Enchanted Tales'

Comment: I've had a look through [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_based_on_Arthurian_legends#Television) and can't really find anything that matches though I didn't check them all. Do any of them ring a bell?

Comment: No, I don't see it.

Comment: Were the knights football players from modern day?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This might help you to improve your question: [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337)

Comment: @JenTibbits Do you know if it was more of a Western-style cartoon or an anime?

Comment: @Jen Tibbits  - You claim that: "It had magic and monsters like all fiction about King Arthur."   Since King Arthur was allegedly a historic person living in a specific time and place, it is perfectly possible to write fiction about him without magic and monsters.  The 12th post here https://www.librarything.com/topic/30684  says: "There's plenty of Arthurian legend retellings that don't involve magic, or does this fall under "alternative history"?"  and see https://www.tor.com/2018/10/17/the-best-arthurian-novels-for-fans-of-actual-history/

Comment: @JenTibbits where did you see this show? Was it american?

Comment: I was on american tv. It looked american. But It could have been from anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [*Camelot*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1125860/?ref_=nm_flmg_prd_11) (1998) as part of the *Enchated Tales* series? I can only find the odd clip of it online, however, there is this clip where the knights put their swords on the table, they get enchanted and they then all thrust them into the air.

There is also this longer montage clip:

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @JenTibbits was ir more childish cartoony than this? I remember as a kid (of the 80s) having a king Arthur cartoon where the people where very squat, it was a comedy cartoon.

Comment: Its not that one, but thank you

Answer (score 2):

The first cartoon that popped into my head was an Oz series from the late sixties/ early seventies that was aired in the UK a few times in the eighties.

*[Arthur! and the Square Knights of the Round Table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur!_and_the_Square_Knights_of_the_Round_Table)*

[image: Imagery from the show]

[image: DVD cover showing Lancelot, Arthur and the jester]

Comment: Hmm... answering whether this is a match might answer the question of whether the animation was realistic-looking or cartoony. :)

Answer (score 2):

It could be [*"King Arthur & the Knights of the Round Table" ("Entaku no Kishi Monogatari Moero Āsā")*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur_(TV_series)), another anime series (*very* loosely) based on the Arthurian legends.

It originally aired in 1979 in Japan, and dubbed versions were broadcasted in the following years in many countries, which fits your timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Could it possibly be *The Legend of Prince Valiant*? It came out at the beginning of 1990 and it centers around Camelot, although the story is technically about Prince Valiant.

In my own searches I seem to have confused one series with the other, so I gave this suggestion in case it could be the answer.

Comment: FWIW I came upon this in my searches, I'm not the question asker, but the intro didn't seem to match. Could you also [edit] this to be a bit more detailed and how it matches the OPs description?

Answer (score 0):

It’s this I looked for ages it’s from 1990 in NZ when I watched it

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Are you Jen Tibbits? If not, could you explain why you believe this is the show Jen is looking for? How does it match their description?